# How do compilers treat CONST qualifier when the pointer points to a memory location obtained with malloc()?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, linux-mint

I really do not know how to put a better title so please be patient with me and have mercy.

**What I know.**

When I do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ){
    const char *arr = "Hello";

    arr[0] = 'B';
    printf( "Arr = %s\n", arr );
}
```

I won't get a `segfault` because applying that `const` qualifier I made a promise to the compiler that I am not going to touch that value where `arr` points to.

At least on my system ( Linux mint 18.3 with GCC 7.2.0) I get:

```
program.c:6:16: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*arr’
         arr[0] = 'B';
                ^
```

**NEXT**

When I do:

```
const char *const arr = "Hello";
```

Like in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ){
    const char *const arr = "Hello";

    while ( *arr != '\0' ){
        arr++;
    }
    printf( "Arr = %s\n", arr );
}
```

The compiler also knows that I promise to not increment the pointer and it see it:

```
program.c:7:16: error: increment of read-only variable ‘arr’
             arr++;
                ^~
```

**What I do not Understand.**

How exactly do compilers treat a situation like this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void ){
    const char *const arr = calloc( 256 * sizeof( *arr ), sizeof( *arr ) );

    strcpy ( (char*)arr , "Hello" );
    printf( "Arr = %s\n", arr );

    free ( (char*)arr );
}
```

Here I am forced to cast `arr` when I call `strcpy()` and same for `free()`.
But why the compiler does not see (ignores) the fact that even if I made a "promise" that I will not try to modify that variable it ignores the `const` qualifier?

Moreover, when I do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void ){
    const char *const arr;

    while ( *arr != '\0' ){
        arr++;
    }

    free ( (char*)arr );
}
```

The compiler sees that I am trying to increment the pointer:

```
program.c:9:16: error: increment of read-only variable ‘arr’
             arr++;
                ^~
```

But ignores the fact that I made a promise that I will not modify the value.

Does the fact that the `malloc` is involved here have a meaning somehow to the compiler that it needs to ignore all those `const` qualifiers`? ...
Or am I missing something important here?

Comment: *but why the compiler does not see (ignores) the fact that even if I made a "Promise" that I will not try to modify that Variable* isn't that the point of the cast? To tell the compiler "hey treat this variable as this and not as that".

Comment: C compilers are under no obligation to always fail when you do something wrong. That would be far too helpful.

Comment: Whether a pointer has `const`  actually has *nothing whatsoever* to do with whether what it points to can change. `const` is basically a thing you can optionally use to protect yourself from your own mistakes, but it doesn't mean very much to the computer.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, bu the compiler see this ` char const* arr` but it can not see this ` const char *arr`

Comment: `const char* arr` and `char const* arr` mean exactly the same thing

Comment: @immibis I am asking about `const  char *arr` vs `const char *const arr` which are not the same.

Comment: The compiler "sees" `const char *` but you explicitely tell the compiler to close an eye or two and treat it as `char *` when you cast your pointer: `(char*)arr`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are allowed to remove `const` from a pointer if it was not `const` originally.

`calloc` returns a `void *`. When you assign it to a `const char *`, you add `const`. But the rules of C allow you to add `const` temporarily and remove it later. You might want to do this, for example, when some routines create data, then give the data to some other routines that should only read the data, but, later, the pointer is passed back to be freed or further changed, in which case `const` must be removed.

In short, `const` is a convenience for software that wants to obey the rules. It asks the compiler to notify you when you accidentally try to write with a `const` pointer. It does necessarily stop you from deliberately breaking the rules by removing `const` inappropriately.

(To be more precise about the opening sentence: C is very flexible about pointer conversions. You can largely convert different types of pointers, as long as alignment requirements are met. It is actually using pointers to access memory that runs into trouble when done incorrectly.)

Comment: `But the rules of C allow you to add const temporarily and remove it later` This is the part which I was not understand it. All answers are OK, but I can only one accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Part of this is very simple:

```
strcpy ( (char*)arr , "Hello" );
```

See that `(char*)`? When you do that, you take back the promise.  If you had written

```
strcpy (arr, "Hello");
```

with no cast, the compiler would have objected.

The other part of this is understanding that `const` annotations on pointers in C are only weakly connected to whether or not the pointed-to memory location is writable.  Heap blocks returned by `malloc` and `calloc` are always in a memory area that *is* writable.  When you set a `const` pointer to point to a heap block returned by `malloc`, the compiler will object to any attempt to write through that pointer, but if you cast away the `const` (take back the promise), or if you just ignore the warning, the write will work fine at runtime, because the memory area is still writable even though the pointer was `const`.

Conversely, string literals are usually in a memory area that *isn't* writable.  You can still refer to them using non-`const` pointers, and the compiler won't object to you writing through those pointers, but the writes *won't* work at runtime, because the memory area is read-only.  And *data objects* declared with `const` (e.g. `const int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`) are also put in a read-only memory area, so again you can't write to them — whether or not you do it through a non-`const` pointer.

It is usually possible to change whether a memory area is writable, but you have to use operating system functions like [mprotect](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect).  Casts don't do that for you -- they usually don't generate any code at all, in fact.

Comment: This is another prove of being not a good Idea to just put a cast to fix a compiler Warning.

Comment: @Michi Yes, indeed.  Always try to understand why the compiler is complaining before you try to "shut it up."

Comment: I wanted to know why this is happens, because [Something like This](https://pastebin.com/raw/wYtjySZe) leads to `segfault` and not to a compiler warning like in the case [Of this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/RLbLSwPS) where the compiler catch it

Comment: "variables declared with const are also put in a read-only memory area"  sounds like a contradiction: How can something that is a _variable_ be  `const` or _read-only_?  I like the spec _object_ to avoid that.  Still UV for good answer.

Comment: @Michi Yep, that's no different than `char *hello = "Hello"; strcpy(hello, "Bonjour");` — the pointer is not `const` but the data pointed to is in read-only memory.  The compiler only checks `const`, but the CPU only checks whether the memory is read-only.

Comment: @chux In strictly proper C11-ese, "variable declared with `const`" would be "object defined with a const-qualified type", but I thought that was too much jargon.

Comment: @Michi Isn't that what I said would happen?  In both my example and yours, the pointer is not `const`, so you get no warnings, but the memory is read-only, so you get a segfault.

Comment: @zwol I deleted my last Commend. I noticed the Point to late :D

Comment: @Michi Something else you may not realize is that "passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type" is effectively the same diagnostic as "assignment of read-only location", even though they sound very different and one of them is only a warning.

Comment: @zwol I noticed that and I was concentrating myself only to the declaration of `arr` and not of what was really happening after that.

Answer (score 2):

A `const` that applies directly to a variable definition means that the value of that variable can never change.

But when a pointer points to a `const` type, that does NOT mean the thing it points to will never change, only that it cannot be changed via that particular pointer.

For example, this program is entirely valid:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char str[] = "abcd";
    const char* p = str;
    str[0] = 'x';
    printf("%s\n", p); /* Prints "xbcd" */
    return 0;
}
```

Note the data `p` points to was changed via its original object, even though `p` is declared as pointing to const.  And then `p` continues to point at the object `str[0]` which has a new value.

In your `calloc` example, there is no `const` variable definition, so the data is not guaranteed to be unchanged.  You made a promise not to change it via `arr` only.  But then the explicit cast creates another pointer that doesn't have the `const` restriction, and it's fine to change that originally non-const data using it.

Comment: " means that the value of that variable can never change." is more like "means that attempting to change the value is UB".  It might work, it might not, code may crash, etc.

Comment: @chux Both are true. Or okay, maybe "can never change in a correct program", but as we know, for a program with UB absolutely all guarantees are void.

Answer (score 1):

The cast to `char *` here

```
strcpy ( (char*)arr , "Hello" );
```

makes compiler ignore your promise *in this place only*.

If the object `arr` points to was originally created as non-const, then you're fine. If not, then it's *undefined behaviour* and you risk getting a segfault.